# Print Data from Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the values of some data in SQL server as follows

```
ID  Currency    Denomination
1   NGN         5.00;10.00;20.00;50.00;100.00;200.00;500.00;1000.00
2   USD         1.00;2.00;5.00;10.00;20.00;50.00;100.00
3   GBP         5.00;10.00;20.00;50.00
4   EUR         5.00;10.00;20.00;50.00;100.00;200.00;500.00;
```

Now I want to print the values in the respective columns using SQL stored procedures. I have this SQL statement as thus

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SwitchMyCurrency

@Currency varchar (50) = null

AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT * FROM [SmartBoxData].[Denomination_SMO] WHERE Currency = @Currency
    IF(@Currency = 'USD')
        BEGIN
           PRINT Denomination
        END
    ELSE
    IF(@Currency = 'GBP')
        BEGIN
           PRINT Denomination
        END
    IF(@Currency = 'EUR')
        BEGIN
           PRINT Denomination
        END
    ELSE
    IF(@Currency = 'NGN')
        BEGIN
           PRINT Denomination
        END
END
GO
```

I am getting this error:

```
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SwitchMyCurrency, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
The name "Denomination" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SwitchMyCurrency, Line 17 [Batch Start Line 0]
The name "Denomination" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SwitchMyCurrency, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 0]
The name "Denomination" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SwitchMyCurrency, Line 26 [Batch Start Line 0]
The name "Denomination" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

Comment: `PRINT Denomination` doesn't make sense. `Denomination` has no context in that statement. You should really be looking at your design  here though; you should avoid storing delimited data in an RDBMS at *all* costs.

Comment: @Larnu, What did I miss Pls

Comment: This is the statement you want to execute: `PRINT Denomination`. What is `Denomination` here, how is sql server supposed to know what you mean?

Comment: @Tarell, included expected results in your question for clarity..

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `print`?  Why not just use the `select`?

```
SELECT Denomination
FROM [SmartBoxData].[Denomination_SMO]
WHERE Currency = @Currency AND
      @Currency IN ('USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'NGN');
```